# How to check if a query returned something in firebase databse?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a query like given below,

```
Query query = mDbRefusers_chat.child("chatId");
```

Now I want to check if that query exists. that is I want to check if a child with the name "chatId" exists. How to do that ?

Comment: actually that has not solved the problem. Its giving me the following exception.' java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.iworld.daxi/com.iworld.daxi.UserChatActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to call observer method'   @Peter Haddad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chat_id");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
  if(dataSnapshot.exist() {

      }
    }
  @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

     }
 });
```

using `dataSnapshot.exist()` it will check if the child `chat_id` exists in the database.